# Putting an entity in hierarchy, or as an attribute with lookup table?

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database

Let's say my company is producing medical products, these products are used in many different lab testing instruments. The business logic hierarchy goes like this:

```
A lab has multiple locations (Up to thousands)
A location has multiple departments (Chemistry, Hematology, 3-5 per location)
A department has multiple instruments (No more than 10-20 instruments per location)
An instrument has many products.(No more than 1-5 product types per instrument)
```

The table structure currently mirrors the business logic, like displayed on the left. I suggested we make a small change, displayed on the right.

[image]

What are some pros and cons of each approach? I feel like the left-hand side approach might be a bit slower due to chaining so many `Joins` in a row.

Comment: Hard to judge a schema without knowing the `SELECTs` that will be used.  And, sometimes writing a `SELECT` points out a flaw in the schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest "con" I see to the approach on the right-hand side is that you lose the association between Department and Location.  For the relationships that you described atop your post, the structure on the left is correct from a design perspective.

HOWEVER...

The design that you have means that the Mass Spectrometer at your San Antonio facility will have a different ID than the one at your Denver facility.  Is that intended?

------------------  revision after discussion in comments  ------------------

You've described a couple of many-to-many relationships - a location will have multiple instruments and multiple locations can have the same instrument (e.g. Mass Spectrometer).  To support that, you'll need cross-reference tables.  Here's an initial sketch.  My standard is to call the table's primary key "ID", and any field called "[table-name]_ID" is a foreign key to the corresponding table:

```
Lab
    ID
    Name

Location
    ID
    Lab_ID
    Street_Address
    City
    etc.

Department
    ID
    Name

Location_Department    -- this lists the departments at a given location
    ID
    Department_ID
    Location_ID

Instrument        -- Scale, Oscilloscope, Mass Spectrometer, etc.
    ID
    Name
    Description

Location_Department_Instrument    -- inventory at a given location
    Location_Department_ID
    Instrument_ID
    Instrument_Serial_Number
```

Let me know if this makes sense.

Comment: The mass spectrometer at San Antonio should have the same instrument_id as the one in Palo Alto, but a different PK id. Is there something else I should change?

Also, does losing the relationship between department and location matter? Most labs have the same departments. In the same sense that most companies have an HR department, a finance department, etc.

Comment: Ahhh -- I think I see what you're trying to do.  Give me a few minutes and I'll update my main answer with a couple of thoughts.

Comment: Oh you're right, I didn't notice the many to many relationship! Thank you.

Comment: Also, is that `Location_Department_Instrument` bridging `Location_Department` and `Instrument`? Shouldn't it be bridging `Department` and `Instrument`?

Comment: Nevermind, I think I understand. Is this what your design is? https://i.imgur.com/kDHsefJ.png

Comment: Yep.  You got it.